# SQL Join across multiple tables and order by single column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am trying to join multiple tables and order the data based on a common column that they share. Here is an example:

**Table A**

```
    pk  itemId  text
    1   10      ordered
    1   5       make
    1   8       it
    1   4       not
```

**Table B**

```
    pk  itemId  text    variable
    1   6       sense   94
    1   1       this    99
    1   2       text    98
```

**Table C**

```
    pk  itemId  text    anotherVariable
    1   3       does    97
    1   7       unless  93
    1   9       is      91
```

I need the final table to look like this:

**Result Table**

```
    pk  itemId  text    variable
    1   1       this    99
    1   2       text    98
    1   3       does    97
    1   4       not     NULL
    1   5       make    NULL
    1   6       sense   94
    1   7       unless  93
    1   8       it      NULL
    1   9       is      91
    1   10      ordered NULL
```

I am using the following query but it is not working...

```
    SELECT *
    FROM tableA as A
    INNER JOIN tableB as B ON A.pk = B.pk
    INNER JOIN tableC as C ON A.pk = C.pk
    ORDER BY A.itemId, B.itemId, C.itemId
```

**Edit:**
added another variable to further explain my problem, across the tables I do not always have the same column names on all tables. On other tables there may be different columns that I want included in the result table.

Comment: Why don't you simply do what you say you want to do and order your results by the shared column?

Comment: @DanBracuk With the join there is no 'shared [item] column'..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` instead.

```
SELECT pk, itemId, [text], variable = NULL FROM TableA UNION ALL
SELECT pk, itemId, [text], variable FROM TableB UNION ALL
SELECT pk, itemId, [text], anotherVariable FROM TableC
ORDER BY pk, itemId
```

---

As long as you have the same number of columns in all of the `SELECT` statements, and all columns have the same data type, `UNION ALL` should work.

Here is the documentation for [**`UNION`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx).

Comment: @MikeK, ahaha. Classic copy-paste mistake. Thank you!

Comment: UNION is what I needed. I keep forgetting about all the different things you can do with SQL, so I have to look things up. Thanks.